# How to create editable buttons/label in swift

Tags: swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiWx5.png)I have a requirement to create user interaction enabled button or label.Can we create it?
And I have tried with disabling the textfield when user taps outside the textfield.But couldn't get it done.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
{
let currentCellDescriptor = getCellDescriptorForIndexPath(indexPath)
                let cell:ArrowCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "\(idString)") as! ArrowCell
                cell.currentMinimumValueTextField.delegate = self
                cell.currentaximumvaluextield.delegate = self

     cell.currentMinimumValueTextField.isEnabled = false
                cell.currentaximumvaluextield.isEnabled = false
}

 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.isEnabled = true
        print("TextField did begin editing method called")

    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("TextField did end editing method called\(textField.text!)")
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder();
        return true;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add proper code, what you have tried?

Comment: have edited the question with code

Comment: One more problem Im facing is on click of textfield in the row is getting selected....I want text field to be selected ....should allow the user to enter text....when user taps outside the textfield textfield should be disabled....Text field should behave like a label

Comment: it is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply.
I found a solution using textfield delegates.On clicking outside of the text field I'm disabling the textfields.With this aproach I'm able to edit and display the slider value in textfields.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
{

    if (textField.tag == 1){
        let min = textField.text
        print(min)
        appDelegate.updatedsliderprice = true
        appDelegate.pricesliderlowerValue = Double(min!)!
    }
    else
   {
       let max = textField.text
        print(max)
    appDelegate.updatedsliderprice = true
    appDelegate.pricesliderupperValue = Double(max!)!
   }
    rangeSliderValueChanged(RangeSliderValue: rangeSlider)
    tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 2), with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
}
```